# What program can open TIFF G4 fax file?

Tags: tiff, fax, image-viewer

I have an old Panasonic fax connected to an old 'fax server'. The fax system produces .tiff files that I just can't open using many viewer; they would simply show a page filled with horizontal lines. I've tried IrfanView and XnView, both failed.

Panasonic provided a tiff viewer that can open the .tiff file, but it's not compatible with Windows 7.

I've uploaded a sample file here: http://www.2shared.com/photo/UwMb11nD/RCV00209.html

Can anyone recommend me a viewer that can open that file?

Answer (score 0):

`GIMP` should be able to open those. `gs` is also available for Windows as `gswin32`.